# Where is the spring context initialized for Spring MVC when we switch to java based configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat9

I am currently following some tutorials to try and learn more about Spring for a future internship, at the moment I am looking at Spring MVC.

The project I was working on was based on xml configuration initially. My assumption of how Spring is initialized was as follows:

1. Tomcat reads my `web.xml` file (knows the file name and it is in a known location)
2. Therefore creates a servlet that is an instance of `DispatcherServlet`
3. The `DispatcherServlet` kicks off spring (knows the name of the config file by a naming convention)

I have now changed the application to get rid of the xml files completely. The configuration now happens in a class I have defined called `SpringConfigFile` annotated with @Configuration, @ComponentScan etc.

I also now have a class I created called `WebInitializer` which extends `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` which seems to be responsible for creating the DispatcherServlet, I have implemented the abstract methods which seem to be responsible for identifying the configuration class and the servlet mappings etc. So I *think* that the instantiation of this class creates the DispatcherServlet which in turn (either directly or indirectly) creates the Application context.

But what is confusing me is where is the instance of `WebInitializer` created? Where is this all kicked off from? In the xml based configuration, you can more clearly follow how the application is initialized: tomcat looks in a fixed place for an xml file it knows should exist, instantiates an object from the information found there that kicks off Spring.

But how does this work without these xml files? I can name my `WebInitializer` class anything I want and put it in any package I want? Does tomcat just search everywhere for something extending 
`AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`?

Answer (score 1):

Found the information I was looking for.

Any instance that implements `WebApplicationInitializer` is automatically detected by `SpringServletContainerInitializer` which itself is bootstrapped by any servlet 3.0 container.

`AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` implements `WebApplicationInitializer` therefore is automatically detected.

More information here:

[WebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html)

[The bootstrapping mechanism](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html)